# Apple Mac Security - What do I need to know?

Tags: operating-systems, macos

As I've been working on Windows machines most of my life I know most of the best practices and apps to keep them secure.

When it comes to security on Apple macs I'm clueless as to where to start.

Comment: Hi @firefusion, welcome to [security.se]! As you are new to the site, please take a moment to review the [FAQ]. Also, if you browse around the site - especially those tagged [tag:macosx] - you'll probably find some relevant questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this webpage is a very good start:

[Mac OS X Security Configuration Guides](http://www.apple.com/support/security/guides/)

You can download on it several *Configuration Guides* and *Security Configuration Guide* for **Mac OS X 10.3 (Panther)** to **10.6 (Snow Leopard)** (but unfortunately right now, not for the latest version **1.7 (Lion)**).

Answer (score 1):

The NSA as a very interesting [section](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/mitigation_guidance/security_configuration_guides/index.shtml) in their site which is dedicated to security configuration guides for various applications, protocols, and operating systems. In their Mac OS section, they have two PDF guides: [hardening tips](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/factsheets/macosx_10_6_hardeningtips.pdf) and [security configuration](http://images.apple.com/support/security/guides/docs/SnowLeopard_Security_Config_v10.6.pdf). (Note: the latter PDF link is actually to a PDF hosted on apple.com).